# Flask redirect function redirects to raw API Gateway url instead of custom domain

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, serverless, zappa

I am using the redirect function in my flask app, but whenever the function triggers it redirects the autogenerated API Gateway domain instead of my own domain, which in turn gives me a message forbidden because it is and was internal url. It works when I run in localhost but as soon as it's AWS it doesn't work. I am using a cloudfront distro to redirect users from http to https.

zappa version: 0.48.2, 
python: 3.6, 
zappa_settings.json:

```
{
  "dev": {
      "app_function": "application.application",
      "aws_region": "eu-north-1",
      "profile_name": "default",
      "project_name": "root",
      "runtime": "python3.6",
      "s3_bucket": "example bucket",
      "domain": "example.com",
      "use_precompiled_packages": true,
      "route53_enabled": true
    }
}
```

it should redirect to example.com instead it redirects to auto generated aws link

Comment: What's your `redirect` code? Are you doing `redirect(url_for('app.index'))` or `redirect('example.com')`?

Comment: I'm doing `redirect('/example')`. But I have tried the url_for method but had the same problem.

Comment: `redirect('/example')` will take you back to your server, notice the `/`. Try be explicit where you want to redirect to e.g. `redirect('www.google.com') ` .